# Dynamic Default Value for Combobox in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, default

I want to set a dynamic default value for my combobox : `combo11`

I used this :

```
Me.Combo11.DefaultValue = DLookup(str)
```

While :

```
str = "EmpOperation", "tblEmp", "EmpNom ='" & Me.Label6.Caption & "'"
```

I am open to any non-VBA solution to this.
Thanks

Full code :

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

        If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
            Me.Label6.Caption = Me.OpenArgs
        End If

        Me!Combo11.DefaultValue = DLookup("EmpOperation", "tblEmp", "EmpNom ='" & Me.Label6.Caption & "'")

End Sub
```

I get #NAME? error on the top value of my combo11

Comment: Huh? `str = "EmpOperation", "tblEmp", "EmpNom ='" & Me.Label6.Caption & "'"` is a compile error, expected end of statement as soon as you navigate away from that line

Comment: Can you correct me sir, I'm new to this

Comment: Start by providing all code as you're using it, with any errors. Then I can see what you're actually doing and might be able to help

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I edited my question with more details and the full code thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !

It's as simple as removing the `.defaultvalue` proprety :

```
Me.Combo11 = DLookup("EmpOperation", "tblEmp", "EmpNom ='" & Me.Label6.Caption & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Me!Combo11.DefaultValue = Nz(DLookup("EmpOperation", "tblEmp", "EmpNom ='" & Me.Label6.Caption & "'"))
```

Comment: Same problem! I get #NAME? error on the default value of the combobox.